# JavaFX disable default action on a single TextField

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, default, javafx-11

I have a form in JavaFX and I have setup a default button so that whenever I press enter while editing any of the text fields the action bound to the button is performed.
The issue that I have is that I would like to disable this behavior on a single text field, and I could not find a solution to this.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

EDIT:
I found out that using

```
inputField.onActionProperty().set()
```

instead of

```
inputField.onActionProperty().addListener()
```

works

Comment: Does consuming (i.e. `event.consume()`) in the action event handler help?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to retrieve the event target and check if it's the one that should be avoided, something like this.

```
final EventTarget target = event.getTarget();

if (code == KeyCode.ENTER && target instanceof TextField) {
    // Do casting stuff then...
    if(target != myTextField)
       doSomething();
    else
       dont();
}
```

Comment: This works but in my case the answer provided by @Slaw worked just fine, i still learned a few things from your answer though, thanks a bunch!